# How can I exclude few fields from validation in forms

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have 10 fields in a Django form like this

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    student_number                 = forms.CharField(required=False)
    final_date                      = forms.DateField(required=False)
    location_area                   = forms.FloatField(required=False)
```

In my `form.is_valid()` I want to exclude few fields from validation like

`[location_area, final_date]` and rest all perform validation or only want to validate `charfields` not `select fields`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Meta` class of form you can exclude fields:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    # form fields here
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('location_area', 'final_date',)
```

If you do not want to exclude fields from form and still don't want to validate them then write a custom field clean method for form which does nothing:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    # form fields here

    def clean_location_area(self):
        location_area = self.cleaned_data['location_area']
        return location_area
```

Comment: i only want to exclude from validation but still want to display them on the form

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work because `field.clean` is called before the `clean_%s % name` so i still get the validation error . https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L292

Comment: why you want to work with unsanitized data? atleast you should validate the proper type of field. This will lead to database error if you even try to save `char` in `integer` field.

Comment: or if you want to allow user to leave particular field empty then change your model and allow on field `null=True, blank=True`

Comment: Actually that form is only for searching and i am not inserting anything in database , i only want to validate text fields not select box fields. Due to having custom ModelMUltipleChoiceField , i am getting error in that field. For temp solution , i ahve overridden `def _clean_fields(self):` but i was looking for proper solution

Comment: @user2392209 Have you set `required=Falase` on your `ModelMultipleChoiceField`?

Comment: @AustinPhillips its not empty thing which cause me error but i have overridden the multiple choice with different value and that is casuing the error during validtaiuon

Comment: @user2392209 Ok, in that case Aamir's solution makes perfect sense. ie override the `clean_xxx` functions for the fields you want ignored, and have the functions do no validation.

Comment: @AustinPhillips but that method is called after validation . see here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L292

Comment: @user2392209 Perhaps you need to subclass `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with one whose `clean` method doesn't do any validation.

Comment: @AustinPhillips THANK YOU this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can override **init** method of your form:
Eg

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
# form fields here

def __init__(self, post_data=None, post_files=None):
     if post_data and post_files:
         self.base_fields.remove(field_name)
         super(SearchForm, self).__init__(post_data, post_files)
     else:
         super(SearchForm, self).__init__()
```

So, basically while you get the form you can use: `SearchForm()`
and while you post data to the form you can use: `SearchForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.
In `__init__` method we are checking whether the request is post or get using `post_data` and `post_files`. So, if it is post we are removing the field from `base_field` so that it won't check for validation for that field.

*Tested in Django 1.11*

Comment: It may be worthwhile clarifying if your answer - is it applicable to all Django versions (including those likely used by the OP) or is it version specific?

Comment: I am not sure about all the django versions but I have tried on 1.11

Comment: The Django source for `forms.Form` states: "The `base_fields` class attribute is the *class-wide* definition of fields. Because a particular *instance* of the class might want to alter `self.fields`, we create `self.fields` here by copying `base_fields`.
Instances should always modify `self.fields`; they should not modify `self.base_fields`."

Comment: Basically values in self.fields comes once __init__ method is called of forms.Form so if we want to do some modification before calling __init__ of forms.Form then we have to use base_fields